# Create a link in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a simple link in CodeIgniter, but I can't do it, because when I click on the link I display the following message:

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

I tried to create the link in several ways but all failed.

First attempt:

I type imagenes/login">Login

Imagenes is a folder that its path is EasyPHP/CodeIgniter/www/imagenes and where a file login.php can be found.

Second attempt:

I type login

And this is the code of my controller:

```
<?php
  class Blog extends CI_Controller 
   {
 public function index()
 {
    $this->load->view('test');

 }

 public function login()
 {
    $this->load->view('login');
 }
    }
   ?>
```

Third attempt:

I type Login

The Url helper is loaded in the autoload.php file.

Maybe the problem is in .htacess file. I have three .htacess files in several folders: EasyPHP/www/CodeIgniter/application
EasyPHP/www/CodeIgniter/application/cache
EasyPHP/www/CodeIgniter/system

In all of these files I have the same code:

Deny from all

I don't know if this file must be changed. If so, which one? and What I must to type?

I am using Codeigniter version 2.1

Any ideas about the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added this url to your routes.php? Try adding: $route['login'] = 'blog/login'; to your routes.php.

Answer (score 1):

The URL for your link should be something like

`http://localhost:8888/codeigniterappfolder/index.php/blog/login`

The login.php view should be located in `/codeigniterappfolder/application/views/login.php`